# node jquery ajax servie side can not get data

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I'm a chinese,so my english is bad,and I give two pitcures to show my question
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Daqq2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydXJZ.png)

and if I go to localhost:8000/get and the page is empty。req.body.length is empty   why?

Comment: Please post actual code in your question.

Comment: two pictures contain my code or I am not understand your meaning?

Comment: It is preferred to not have to go see your code off this site. Generally all questions should contain relevant code right in the question.

Comment: You are accessing `request.query.length` in your pictures. Try sending the data like `/get?length=231231&height=5235345` then you will see them under `request.query`

Comment: I know I should sending data.but I have already sendding data in index.html by ajax。but I can not see anything in request.query。but if I submit by from 。I can see sonething under request.query,  why?

Answer (score -1):

Also, here is working code using GET.

```js
var express = require('express');

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, rs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(rs);
        }
    });

    res.render('index.html');
});
app.get('/get', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query.length)
    res.send("Hello from Get");
});

app.listen('8800', function(err) {
    console.log('Listening on 8800')
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

    Hello
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/get',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                    length: '12',
                    height: '122323'
                },
                success: function() {
                    console.log("success")
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

You are using Get method inside $.ajax. If you want to send data in the body of ajax call you need to use Post method (type:'POST').